# Why my angular project UI display in Windows os different and Mac os different?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, user-interface

I'm facing issues related to UI of my theme which is in angular 6.The problem is that UI display in Windows OS is different and bigger but in mac it's not. i made theme in MAC OS.
IN WINDOWS OS [screenshot from Windows os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9233G.jpg)

IN MAC OS [screenshot from mac os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47YGI.png)

Comment: In the same browsers?

Comment: Are you sure you've not accidentally zoomed in on the content on your Windows machine? STRG+0 would do the trick.

Comment: @JensHabegger Please check screen shot i added.

Comment: @arvymetal yes browsers are same.

Comment: @VaibhavBorle Have you checked your zoom level?

Comment: You're using a different font on each OS, and the screens appear to be different sizes -- those might be the whole explanation right there.  We really can't diagnose this from screenshots, though; can you put together a [mcve] so we don't have to guess at what might be going on?